# Creating Angular modal directive that appears on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to recreate the same functionality as myspace.com. Basically what they have is a search modal that appears automatically as soon as you start typing anywhere on the page (any keypress).

I have the code in this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Cw6isK?p=preview

I can't quite get it to work. In essence what I'm trying to do is make a directive that listens for keypress events on $document. Then as soon as it picks a keypress up- opens the quickSearch modal with a search box so that the user can continue typing his/her search query.

The problem is I can't get it to work. I can't figure out a way to bind/link the keypresses to the directive search input box.

```
app.directive('quickSearch', function($timeout, $document) {
return {
restrict: 'AE',
templateUrl: 'quickSearch.html',
scope: {
  selected: '=',
  isOpen: '@'
},
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  var arr = [];
  $document.bind('keyup', function(e) {
    scope.selected.isOpen = true;
    //here i'm trying to link/bind the keypresses to the scope, but not sure if this is a good way of doing it
    scope.selected.query += e.key
  });


  scope.$watch('scope.selected.isOpen', function() {
    if(scope.selected.isOpen){
    $timeout(function() {
      elem.find('input')[0].focus()
    }, 1)          
    }

  })
}
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just forgot that DOM events bound manually (not with ng* directives) don't trigger new digest cycle automatically. So you just need to kick off digest manually. Also, you probably want something like `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);` instead of `e.key` and do it on `peypress` event:

```
$document.bind('keypress', function(e) {
  scope.selected.isOpen = true;
  scope.selected.query += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  scope.$apply();
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/xJoWvlTXxO94Ntgx2uy8?p=info

Comment: Ok, that works- but I still have the problem of binding the model on ng keypress. I want to bind whatever search query is typed to the input box in the directive